# How to compute the time difference with grace period using php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, backend

I have an html table and it is populated by data from database in our project. The idea is that, the table will automatically compute the time difference considering the grace period of 15 minutes for time-in and 29 minutes for time-out and show the result on total working hours column. So that the employee will not be considered as late when they arrived at 8:15 for example. I got the difference covered but I still can't figure out the calculation for grace period. Can someone help me on this problem? Can I do the computation on mysql or php?

Here's the code:

```
$start_time = explode(":",$list->m_time);   //where m_time = 10:32

$start_time_hr = $start_time[0];
$start_time_min = $start_time[1];

$start_tot_min = intval($start_time_hr*60) + $start_time_min;

$end_time = explode(":",$list->mx_time);   //where mx_time = 11:45

$end_time_hr = $end_time[0];
$end_time_min = $end_time[1];

$end_tot_min = intval($end_time_hr*60) + $end_time_min; //converting hour to min + min

$total_min_diff = intval($end_tot_min - $start_tot_min);

$hr_diff = intval($total_min_diff/60);

$min_diff = intval($total_min_diff%60);

echo $hr_diff.".".$min_diff."";
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @MrYellow Thanks for your help. I've already try this but i need to consider the grace period and i have no idea how to add it.

Comment: Maybe some code will help. Couldn't you just add the 15mins to their time before the datediff and reduce the difference window by the same amount?

Comment: @MrYellow Yes I need a code to compute using the grace period. Good point. But why would i reducing the time difference by same amount? Can i add 15 minutes on time in and 29 minutes on time out?

Comment: Just semantics there, if the window is established by adding 30mins, and you've already added 15mins, you only have to add 15mins more instead of 30mins more. All depends on your actual code.

Comment: Im confused. i need to add 15 minutes in time in and consider another 29 minutes in timeout.

Comment: If you post your code, people will rush to answer. Without the code, we're just guessing how you're trying to implement it.